# Clean Architecture: are repositories always needed?

Tags: android, repository, clean-architecture

I'm trying to apply Clean Architecture to a mobile Android App, but I still have some doubts about how to manage API calls.

Currently, the classes are structured like this:

View -> ViewModel -> UseCase -> Repository -> DataSource

It's all well and good when the API calls are about fetching some data from/sending some data to an API. The Repository handles the data I put into it or retrieve from it, and behaves like a collection.

Now, what should I do when my API call has nothing to do with some data I could put in a collection?

**Example:** 
The user hasn't received the "confirm your email" link on his email, so he clicks a button named "Resend Email Confirmation Link". Then, I'll have a `ResendEmailConfirmationUseCase`.

**My question is: should I have a repository to make that API call?**

That doesn't make sense to me, as I'll handle no data, but just send a signal to an API saying "Hey, send that confirmation email again". There is no collection of data that translates into a repository here. How would I even name that repository?

How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't.

You cannot express an action in this framework as an action.

This architecture is about things and is not about actions. Conflating the two is a sure recipe for confusion.

---

If you absolutely must though.

The trick is find a way to communicate the Action in terms of Things.

I can see two approaches:

- turn the action itself into a thing.
- ignore the action and focus on the things that bound the action.

*Action as a Thing*

Instead of calling a function directly, you describe the desired action in a `task`. Save that `task` to the repository and on the server there is a worker responsible for fulfilling each `task`.

In this case a `SendMessageTask` with some parameters indicating what sort of message to send, to whom, etc... The task is consumed when the task is completed.

*Action hidden between States*

Instead of bothering with the action look at the states (things) that surround the action. Save the state which is pre-action into the repository. The server is responsible for waiting for, or performing the action required to transition the state to the next state (post-action).

In this case you would save `Unsent Message` into the repository. At some point a server process loads `Unsent Message`s and then `Sends` them. It deletes the `Unsent Message` and then saves a `Sent Message` or `Undelivered Message` depending on the new next state.

*Perspective*

If you stare hard enough at both solutions, you will see that a task is just a workflow over a set of states, and vice versa states are a breakdown of a task.

That essentially means the solution is identical, it just boils down to what is the more important concept: A Request for Work, or The State of the System.

---

Either way the client does not directly "action" a server activity. The client only describes an action, or a state with an implied action to the server. At some later point the server chooses to fulfil the request for action, or act to transform data in a given repository.

---

Alternately, change this architecture. Add in the ability to instruct the server.

```
View -> ViewModel -> UseCase |---------------------->|-> Repository -> DataSource
                             |-> Agent -> Command ?->|
```

The `UseCase` determines that a business activity is required and instructs the `Agent` to handle it. The `Agent` then orchestrates one or more `Command`s to fulfil the business activity. Those `Command`s may need to interact with the `Repository` or with other systems (such as an email server).

Its a matter requirements and of taste as to where you draw the dotted line for client vs server.

I would place the dotted line down the middle of `Agent`/`Repository`. Having the bulk of implementation on the server, and a proxy with suitable caching, sanity checks, etc... duplicated on the client. This way `Agent`, `Command`, `Repository`, and `DataSource` are truly trustable. `Use Case` would have a question mark, but could not do anything not already permitted by the `Agents`/`Repositories`.

That being said, it could be drawn down the middle of the `UseCases`, or the `ViewModels` just as easily to trade off responsiveness vs trust.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain it so thoroughly.
My takeaway is that I should turn this action into a state on my system. So, I'll have some sort of `EmailConfirmationLink` repository and a state (unsent, sent) in this object meaning that my task was performed or not, by the server.